# replace lowerbody animation of a skeleton while keeping upperbody animation intact?

Tags: animation

i have multiple animations each with same skeleton ,each having same running animation but different upperbody animations,i changed running animation of one file,now i want to change the running animation of all with the one i changed without manually changing each one of them while at same time keeping the upperbody animations of all intact 
so only running animations are replaced,
how can i do that?

Comment: I've done this with bvh (mocap) generated actions, by copying action, and stripping out hips and above in one (running, walking etc) and opposite in other.  Then place two  together using the NLA editor.